# Reach service on VM with private address

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, ip, firewall

I have this configuration:

[image: ss of image]
*source: https://www.lucidchart.com/publicSegments/view/5256a1e5-afb0-4c7a-96fa-35750a00527d/image.png*

Basically, I have to reach a service which is running on the virtual machine with IP address 192.168.0.20 from a remote machine; this service is reachable on the port 80 and is working via a browser. However, I can't modify any firewall configuration on the hypervisor (the physical machine I can reach with its public IP).

Comment: That sound like hypervisor misconfiguration: it should forward traffic for 192.168.0.20 to the target machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to forward the port by a user space program.

I can recommend you [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/), e.g.

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:80,fork,reuseaddr TCP4:192.168.0.20:80
```

It seems that you do not have root rights on the hypervisor. In this case you need to choose a port above 1023 for listening on the hypervisor.

See following question for more options (like [`redir`](http://sammy.net/~sammy/hacks/)): https://serverfault.com/questions/252150/port-forwarding-on-linux-without-iptables